# How to remove array from array if value have related to other value in array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have an array and want to remove the related value form array.

Ex.

> In array [0] have 1/2/3 and [1] have 1/2/3/4 then [0] is a related to [1] so
>   remove [0] which have 1/2/3 from the array.

Another Example is

Ex.

> [2] have 1/2/5, [3] have 1/2/5/6 and [4] have 1/2/5/6/7 then [2] and
>   [3] depends on [4] so remove [2] and [3] both array form array.

For more details please check below example.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/3/4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/5/6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/5/6/7
        )
)
```

Want Output :

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
         (
            [id] => 1/2/3/4
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/5/6/7
        )
)
```

I don't have an idea how can I do that. Is it possible?

Comment: Are the numbers always in order? Like `1/2/6/5` and `1/2/5/6/7`?

Comment: Yes, @Eddie then numbers always in order.

Comment: Like 1/2/3, 1/2/3/4

Comment: @Eddie Is it possible?

Comment: HI @dan08, that are all ids value. [0] have 1/2/3  and [1] have 1/2/3/4 so 1/2/3 have already used in 1/2/3/4 so do not require in an array. I think you can getting now what I m saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the array is in order, you can `array_reverse` the array. Use `array_reduce` to loop thru the array, Use `strpos` to check position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

```
$arr = //your array
$result = array_reduce( array_reverse( $arr ), function( $c, $v ){
    if ( count( $c ) === 0 ) $c[] = $v;
    else if ( count( $c ) && strpos( $c[0]['id'] , $v['id'] ) === false ) array_unshift( $c, $v );      
    return $c;
}, array());

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/3/4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1/2/5/6/7
        )

)
```

Comment: Yes @Eddie Thanks It working properly with proper code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You need to sort the elements first and then it is very straightforward.

```
<?php

$input = [
  [ "id" => "1/2/3" ],
  [ "id" => "1/2/3/4" ],
  [ "id" => "1/2/5" ],
  [ "id" => "1/2/5/6" ],
  [ "id" => "1/2/5/6/7" ]
];

//firstly sort this array in reverse order
//like so 1/2/3/4 is before 1/2/3
usort(
  $input,
  function($e1, $e2) {
    return $e2["id"] <=> $e1["id"];
  }
);

$output = array_reduce(
  $input,
  function($out, $el) {
    if (empty($out)) {
      $out[] = $el;
    } else {
      $lastEl = $out[count($out) - 1];
      //we add element to the result array
      //only if actual last element doesn't begin with it 
      if (strpos($lastEl['id'], $el['id']) !== 0) {
        $out[] = $el;
      }
    }
    return $out;
  },
  []
);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Karol Samborski.